# Use helper methods in rspec before :suite block

Tags: ruby, rspec

A common pattern for using helper methods in rspec would be something like:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

Dir[File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'support', '**', '*.rb'), __FILE__)].each { |f| require f }

###

# spec/suppport/my_helper.rb

module MyHelper
  def do_something
    # ...
  end
end
```

I'd like to call that helper method like so:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MyHelper

  config.before :suite do
    do_something
  end
end
```

But when I try that I get an error like `undefined local variable or method 'do_something'`.  I suspect rspec does some kind of lazy/deferred loading and the helper module does not get included immediately.

If I use `before :each` instead of `before :suite`, then everything works as expected.  Seemingly the module has been included by the time `before :each` runs, but not by the time `before :suite` runs.

In my case the block is idempotent so it's not causing any problems as `before :each`, but it's wastefully inefficient because it really only needs to run once before the suite runs, not before each test.  I do use this method in the specs, so I think it's appropriate to keep it in a helper module, but how can I call it in a `before :suite` block?

I am using `rspec-core 3.4.1`.

Comment: Can't you put it in a `before(:all)` block when necessary? It also keeps test knowledge localized instead of forcing a hunt to see where behavior is coming from.

Comment: @DaveNewton Using `before :all` (or `before :context`) does work (I hadn't tried it).  That makes it functionally equivalent to `before :suite` for me at the moment since I only have one top level example group currently, but that could change and would introduce a similar inefficiency.  It does make sense for this block to run once as a one-time setup / sanity check.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I'm always wary of tucking too much functionality away in the spec helper when it's before tests or suites because it makes things happen that aren't explicitly in the tests. To me, tests are documentation, and those docs include understanding what's necessary for those specific tests. If it's *really* broad functionality ok, but even then I'd almost always rather have an explicitly-included helper library, shared spec, etc.

Answer (score 1):

change this ...

```
Dir[File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'support', '**', '*.rb'), __FILE__)].each { |f| require f }
```

to this ...

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

and also change this ...

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MyHelper

  config.before :suite do
    do_something
  end
end
```

to be this ...

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  include MyHelper

  config.before :suite do
    do_something
  end
end
```